# Error: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, android-fragments, dagger-hilt, navigationcontroller

Fragment is not loading in Unit Test.

Code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class DataFeature  {

    @Test
    fun testEventFragment() {
            val fragmentArgs = bundleOf("test" to "100")
            val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<DetailFragment>(fragmentArgs)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity. Found: class androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity
```

Fragment file

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {....}
```

while I am using Hilt in my application code. It's showing error in test case. It's not launching that fragment. I am using jetpack navigation controller as well.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to downgrade your classpath to

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
```